# How to safely close a THREAD which has a infinite loop in it

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, beginthreadex

I am creating a thread using `_beginthreadex` function. The function address I am passing in it has an infinite while loop (`while(1)`) . I have the `threadid` and `threadhandle`.

I can use `TerminateThread(threadhandle,1);` But it is dangerous.

The safe way is to kill thread using `_endthreadex` but it can only be used from inside the thread, and I wanted to kill the thread from outside.

So please suggest if there is a safe way to close,end or kill the thread safely from outside using `threadid` or `threadhandle`.

Comment: You'll have to fix your code, you need to give the thread an exit condition.  Run dangerous and uncooperative code in another process if necessary.

Comment: is this c **or** c++, windows specific? etc...

Comment: Added winapi tag since this is indeed Windows-specific.

Comment: @UmNyobe yes it is c,c++ windows.

Comment: @Hans  that's the last thing I wanna do , so is there any other way possible to do this.

Comment: @ Lundin thanks...ill remember it next time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You should** - literally - **never use *TerminateThread()*.** And I'm not even joking. If you are terminating a thread from the outside, all resources reserved in it will be leaked, all state variables accessed inside will have an undetermined state and so on.

---

The solution for your problem might be signaling your thread to finish itself. It can be done by a volatile variable changed by thread-safe means (see *InterlockedIncrement()* on that), a Windows event, or something like that. If your thread has a message loop you can even do it by sending a message to ask it to stop.

Comment: Yes I read all this on msdn also. But I thought may be if there is a way to do this (kill thread safely from outside). Actually to modify the while loop that is inside the thread was my last option. But it seems that's the only option.

Comment: @Israwat - Believe me, I develop heavily multithreaded applications (servers mostly), and killing a thread from the outside is a really bad practice leading to enormous headache. Also, if you are using a framework like MFC, you will leak a lot of memory, since MFC threads reserve a lot of memory for background MFC objects.

Answer (score 8):

The proper way is to create an event "kill me", by using CreateEvent, then flag this event when you wish to kill the thread. Instead of having your thread wait `while(1)`, have it wait `while(WaitForSingleObject(hevent_killme, 0))`. And then you can simply let the thread callback finish and return, no need to call _endthreadex or such.

Example of callback function:

```
static DWORD WINAPI thread_callback (LPVOID param)
{
  ...
  while(WaitForSingleObject(hevent_killme, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    // do stuff
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Caller:

```
HANDLE hevent_killme = CreateEvent(...);
...

void killthread (void)
{
  SetEvent(hevent_killme);
  WaitForSingleObject(hthread_the_thread, INFINITE);
  CloseHandle(hevent_killme);
  CloseHandle(hthread_the_thread);
}
```

Never use TerminateThread.

Comment: while(1) loop is inside the thread function. I am not waiting for thread too terminate in an infinite while loop .

Comment: @lsrawat Yes I understood that, my answer is written with that assumption. I'll clarify the answer a bit.

Comment: @Israwat - You don't6 have to. Lundin advises you to examine the state of the event, not the thread.

Comment: Ok now I under stood , I hope its similar to what mg30rg or simurg suggested in below answer.

Comment: @lsrawat Added an example.

Comment: Use a bool variable, then test it everytime in the while(1) loop...?

Comment: @user9000 Events are better, as you can wait for them effectively with your thread/process asleep. Suppose you don't need your thread to work 100% of the time, for example.

Comment: @Lundin I'd rather stay away from Winblows state of the art technologies and use an enum since Winblows successfully defeated the purpose of portable languages.  Using Assembly nowadays is better than coding under Windows

Comment: @user9000 Or even better, don't use a 'while(1)'/'while(true)' loop, but one which has a proper exit condition. (More of an advice than a rule.) You will have a source code easier to maintain, and no additional headache when a problem like this occurs.

Comment: @user9000 Good for you. This question is however about the Windows-specific beginthread() function, so your rant isn't relevant. If it makes you happier, I believe the very same code could be written with POSIX functions instead.

Comment: @Lundin Even if it's Windows specific, pointing OP at portable code is not irrelevant, because it's one of the purposes of C/C++ existent...  Plus, yes, there is POSIX equivalent, pthread condition variables... It all depends on what hes doing exactly, so.  Would suggest C++11 std::condition_variable instead

Comment: @user9000: To someone that doesn't understand the semantics of `volatile`, a portable solution might look simpler than it is. In reality, a portable solution generally adds complexity. The solution offered by Lundin is perfectly valid, and fairly simple to follow.

Comment: @IInspectable Never said it's invalid, I just wanted to state a point nothing more.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `while(1)`, you can use `while(continue_running)`, where `continue_running` is `True` when the thread loop should run. When you want to stop the thread, make the controlling thread set `continue_running` to `False`. Of course make sure that you properly guard `continue_running` with mutexes as it is a variable whose value can be modified from two threads.

Comment: And remember to declare 'continue_running' as volatile, because otherwise optimisation might break your code. (In Visual Studio or gcc, in other IDEs it might differ.)

Comment: @mg30rg on most CPUs, bools are atomic operations

Comment: @user9000 - It is not about booleans but compiler optimization. If your compiler isn't avare of the multithreaded nature of your variable it might caches/replicates/multi-instatiates/skips/etc. it for performance reasons.

Comment: Thread-safety for such a variable might not be a concern anyhow, if there is only one thread setting it to a non-zero value, and another thread reading it. volatile to prevent incorrect optimizations is indeed good practice, but I think most compilers don't make such optimization assumption mistakes nowadays?

Comment: @mg30rg True, it's always a good idea to take extra caution, you might also want to add that volatile will cause it to always read from memory as this is one of the reasons one would use volatile in a single/multi threaded application.

Comment: @Lundin In **most cases** (let's say 85%) it won't cause trouble. Int he remaining cases (let's say 15%) it causes a heisenbug. Does it really worth creating an opportunity of a heisenbug to save yourself some typing?

Comment: @Lundin - I have also met situations where not setting a variable volatile did not cause trouble for years and then on one day when a patch was added to a seemingly unconnected part of the code it started to act strange.

Comment: @mg30rg Ok was curious about the state of mainstream desktop OS compilers, I would have thought they'd solved this by now. I mainly work with embedded systems, where the compilers are generally less smart. In such systems you simply _must_ declare everything shared with a thread/callback/isr as volatile.

Comment: @Lundin - As I hobby I develop PIC software, but PIC18 is not multi-threaded, so I didn't face this issue there. I also develop for my own Raspberry Pi, but I follow the same guidelines  I do when I develop desktop sw.

Comment: @mg30rg You do have the same issue there, whenever you have an interrupt service routine.

Comment: Why the deletion of my answer @martijn-pieters ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters